# When trigged action, mockNavigationController return current viewController, not pushed

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uinavigationcontroller, mocking

I learning TTD, and have problem with navigation controller in Unit-testing.
    When I'm trying to push Detail View Controller through navigation stack (pushViewController(ViewController, animated:) ) with my mock controller, in test push function not perform (its perform only first time, when navigationController initialise).
On simulation iPhone, app work correctly.
    In code mockNavigationController have value pushedVC, that changes when pushViewController perform.
    When user tap on cell, dataProvider (delegate and dataSource for tableCell) post notification to ViewController (sut), that implements showDetails method.

I'd try take topViewController from navigationController:
 sut.navigationController?.topViewController - it's return sut ViewController.
Try not initialise navigationController in test. sut.navigationController?.topViewController - it's return nil.

This beginning of XCTestCase

```swift
var sut: EatersListViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: EatersListViewController.self))
        sut = vc as? EatersListViewController

        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
```

This test function

```swift
func testSelectedRowPushedDetailVC() {
        let mockNavigationController = MockNavigationController(rootViewController: sut)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = mockNavigationController

        let eater1 = Eater(name: "Foo")
        sut.dataProvider.manager!.addEater(eater: eater1)

        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()

        sut.tableView.delegate?.tableView?(sut.tableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

        guard let detailEaterVC = mockNavigationController.pushedVC as? DetailEaterViewController else {
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        detailEaterVC.loadViewIfNeeded()

        XCTAssertNotNil(detailEaterVC.eaterNameLabel)
        XCTAssertEqual(detailEaterVC.eaterData, eater1)
}
```

This function from ViewController

```swift
@objc func showDetails(withNotification notification: Notification) {
        guard
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let eater = userInfo["eater"] as? Eater,
            let detailEaterVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: DetailEaterViewController.self)) as? DetailEaterViewController else { return }
        detailEaterVC.eaterData = eater
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailEaterVC, animated: true)
}
```

And MockNavigationController

```swift
extension EatersListViewControllerTests {
    class MockNavigationController: UINavigationController {

        var pushedVC: UIViewController?

        override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
            pushedVC = viewController
            super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expected that XCTAssert work correct, but every time test failed on XCTFail() line. I think somewhere error, and don't know here.

```swift
XCTAssertNotNil(detailEaterVC.eaterNameLabel)
XCTAssertEqual(detailEaterVC.eaterData, eater1)
```

Need help with code, where I wrong. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11377908/alexander), welcome to StackOverflow.

You say that `dataProvider` is the `.dataSource` and `.delegate` for the `UITableView` in your view controller under test, and that it's the one responsible for starting the navigation.

Are you sure that in the tests `dataProvider` is actually set as the `.dataSource` and `.delegate`? If that's not the case then the code starting the navigation will never be called.

You could use breakpoints to verify two things:

1. If your `showDetails` method is called
2. If the `pushViewController(_:, animated:)` method in your `MockNavigationController` is called

I'm guessing one of them isn't called, and that might point you towards the cause of your issue.

If you allow me, a few extra words:

- I would recommend using the [`NavigationDelegate` pattern](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/navigation-delegate-pattern/) to test this behaviour. It would make it simpler for you, by removing the need to fiddle with `UIApplication`.
- It's better to use `_ = sut.view` or `sut.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)` to trigger the setup of the view controller's view in the tests

Comment: I have test for dataProvider: 
-testDataProviderIsDataSourceForTableView
-testDataProviderIsDelegateForTableView and 
-testWhenViewIsLoadedTableViewDelegateAndDataSourceEquals
They complete correctly

When mockNC initialise, mockPushViewController called with sut VC.
showDetails method triggered, then didSelectRowAt called, and generate normal VC for push.
But after navigationController?.pushViewController(detailEaterVC, animated: true) in showDetails method not triggered mockPushViewController again.

Thanks for answer, I'll try figure out ur recommendation and apply to my tests.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)